# Is Express.js platform-independent?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm just starting out with `Express.js`. In the official getting started guide, they showed the following basic code:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

// respond with "hello world" when a GET request is made to the homepage
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('hello world')
})
```

The first parameter to `app.get()` is a forward-slash indicating the root directory. But the slash is a backward-slash in windows systems. Does express deal with these differences automatically, or do we need to write extra code for it? When I was using the `http` module, I did have to consider and correct for these differences. Thanks for the help!

Comment: That doesn't indicate the root directory, it's the root *path*. You don't enter URLs with backslashes on Windows...

Comment: URLs use forward slash even on windows. Just look at the url of this question: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63658544/is-express-js-platform-independent`. Did you type `https://stackoverflow.com\questions\63658544\is-express-js-platform-independent` on Windows?

Comment: @slebetman I accidentally thought the `app.get()` method takes that string and passes it directly into the filesystem. The filesystem in windows uses backslashes right? Anyways my bad. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`app.get('/', ...)` declares a handler for when an HTTP GET request is made to the URL path `/`. E.g. `http://localhost:8080/`. It has nothing to do with file paths on the server’s file system. If you use any functions that do take a file path, you may have to account for the differences between Windows and *NIX, that depends on the function.

Comment: Thanks, that what I needed to know!